# Difference between using Split with no parameters and RemoveEmptyEntries option

Tags: c#, split, removing-whitespace

I'm checking lines in a given text file. Lines may have random whitespace and I'm only interested in checking the number of words in the line and not the whitespace. I do:

```
string[] arrParts = strLine.Trim().Split();

if (arrParts.Length > 0)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Now, according to msdn,

```
If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.
```

The `IsWhiteSpace` method covers many diverse forms of whitespace including the usuals: `' ' \t and \n`

However recently I've seen this format used:

`Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

How is this different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the following string:

```
"Some  Words"//notice the double space
```

Using `Split()` will split on white space and will include 3 items ("Some", "", "Words") because of the double space.

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option instructs the function to discount Emtpy entries, so it would result it 2 items ("Some", "Words")

[Here is a working example](http://ideone.com/8Yeqcz)

---

For completeness, the `new char[0]` parameter is supplied in order to access the overload that permits specifying `StringSplitOptions`. In order to use the default delimiter, the separator parameter must be `null` or of zero-length. However, in this case using `null` would satisfy multiple overloads so you must specify a valid type (either `char[]` or `string[]`). This can be done multiple ways, such as `(char[])null` or `null as char[]`, or by using a zero-length char array like above.

[See here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Without using `RemoveEmptyEntries` you might get empty strings in the result array.